# Make SumatraPDF the default PDF application of Kile on Windows

Tags: pdf, kde-plasma

I am using Kile on Windows and I have installed SumatraPDF as well. How do I make 'ViewPDF' use Sumatra?

What I have tried so far:

1. Run Settings -> System Check, hoping to have the PDF viewer detected automatically. Unfortunately, no PDF viewer is recognized at all.
2. Manually create ViewPDF as a Tool. I am using the file path of my PDF viewer and pass the option "%target". Unfortunately, the system complains that it cannot find the *ps file corresponding to the file name. So I presume it accidentally looks for a PS file even though the PDF file works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Kile normally runs some pre-flight system check for LaTeX and Viewer components. However ViewPDF expects those more common on native KDE platform such as Okular or the PdfTeX pre-view so usually fails as non critical ! SumatraPDF will work but usually needs some manual addition. Most other LaTeX IDEs are much easier to configure for Windows use, especially using MiKTeX with its PdfTeX configurations that will accept multiple PDF pre-viewer settings.

Thus older Kile readme used to explain it was best to set it to use the system apps found on "Path" however that was before Windows 10 plus Edge commandeered user file association preferences.

If running Windows 7 (or 8) SumatraPDF could very easily be set as default PDF handler and thus there was less need for any settings in many TeX cases.

This combination is not impossible on Windows 10 as seen here, but even for me (Disclaimer I support SumatraPDF) was a challenge using Kile3 Beta3 in Windows 10.

[image]

Basically you need to set SumatraPDF to be the system default PDF handler, a challenge itself in some instances. Then in Kile ensure all settings for ViewPDF are default. I had to use that restore button on bottom more than once.

[image]